# PostgreSQL: if column1 contains x, y or z set column2 to x,y or z

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of products with uncleaned descriptions that I need to extract attributes from.

i.e:

'large (blue) tank top'

'med wht. W shorts'

etc.

needs to become:

```
size   color   style     gender
large  Blue    Tank top
Medium White   Shorts    women's
```

The list of possible variations is fairly long. Is there a way through postgres to say:

If description contains [blue,white,red] set Color to [returned found color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways.  The most direct is to use `case`:

```
select (case when description like '%blue%' then 'blue'
             when description like '%white%' then 'white'
             when description like '%red%' then 'red'
        end) as color
```

Comment: "Frederick Wrathwhite's bluenosed dolphin" will match all three.

Comment: @NovaDenizen . . . Actually, it would only match "blue" because a `case` chooses the first match.  That is a worthwhile comment to ask the OP:  What to do when there are multiple matches.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Actually ideally everything that has a match should be extracted as an attribute or possible attribute of that style. Then each unique possible combination of sizes and colors for that style needs to be assigned a SKU. That's my project anyway and probably outside the narrow scope of this question but if there are any guides or well known ways to do something like that, i'm all ears.